# Sum of normal densities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $Y$ is a random variable whose distribution is completely known. For $i=1,\dots,d$, $\beta_i$ are positive constants, $g_i(\cdot)$ are exponential functions with the form $g_i(x) = \exp(a_i(x-b_i)^2 + c_i)$, where $a_i,b_i,c_i$ are all constants (can be positive or negative). We also have $\sum_{i}\beta_i = 1$.

I am wondering if there is any way to give an analytical form (in terms of distribution of $Y$) for the probability of the event $\{\sum_{i=1}^d \beta_i g_i(Y)\geq\beta_1g_1(Y)\}?$

Say $Y$ follows some normal distribution. We can easily give a closed form for the probability of the event above for $d\leq2$. But I don't know how to do so for $d=3$; discussing the convexity/monotonicity and searching for equilibriums seem to be too complicated. I would greatly appreciate it if any advice can be given.